# Netty: Shoud i create new ChannelBuffer for sending data to every client?

Tags: java, netty

I have a list of connected clients like SimpleChannelHandler:

```
List<ChannelHandler> clients = new ArrayList<ChannelHandler>();
```

I want to send them data like "Hello" string. Im creating a new ChannelBuffer which contains this data:

```
ChannelBuffer cb = ChannelBuffers.buffer(1024);
cb.writeBytes("Hello".getBytes());
```

And then i want to send this data to all of connected clients. The question is - can i send this data to all of clients using only this channel buffer, or should i create a new channel buffer for every client?
I'm asking because as i know, after calling channel.write(cb) operation -
 ChannelBuffer write index will change, and i have doubts that same buffer will be sent to next client correct.

So, there is two ways. First one, is sending only one ChannelBuffer to all clients:

```
 ChannelBuffer cb = ChannelBuffers.buffer(1024);
 cb.writeBytes("Hello".getBytes());
 for(ChannelHandler ch : clients)
   ch.write(cb)
```

Second one, is to create a new ChannelBuffer for every client:

```
for(ChannelHandler ch : clients) {
  ChannelBuffer cb = ChannelBuffers.buffer(1024);
  cb.writeBytes("Hello".getBytes());
  ch.write(cb)
}
```

Which way is correct?

**UPDATE:**

I made some test, and could say that first way doesnt work. After sending ChannelBuffer first time, channel.write operation will reset writerIndex to zero, and all next clients will not get any info at all.
To solve this problem without using second way, need to do some workaround:

> ```
> ChannelBuffer cb = ChannelBuffers.buffer(1024);
> cb.writeBytes("Hello".getBytes());
> cb.markWriterIndex();
> for(ChannelHandler ch : clients) {
>   cb.resetWriterIndex();
>   ch.write(cb);
> }
> ```

The second ways works too, but it creates a new ChannelBuffer object before every write.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are correct. You may also copy `ChannelBuffer` so you don't have to `cb.writeBytes` every time.

However, I would recommend you to use `StringEncoder` so you could write `String` directly to channel so you don't have to think about `ChannelBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dmitriy. I tested both ways and updated first post. Seems like first way in "pure" view couldn't be used for broadcasting message, i added some details in the first post.

Comment: My bad. I thought you just send byte[] and not ChannelBuffer in the first case. Your approach with resetWriterIndex(); may be wrong. As client channels may be in different EventLoops that may bring you concurrency issue. However, it depends on ChannelBuffer implementation.

Comment: And which approach could be used to solve situation when clients calling send code from different EventLoops? Creating new instance of ChannelBuffer for every client?

Comment: Yeap. You may look into DefaultChannelGroup that is also does copy of buffers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're broadcasting the same (immutable) content to multiple contents, consider using `ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer()`. This creates a wrapped view of the underlying byte array, and you can hand one out to each client without incurring the overhead of copying.

```
byte[] data = "Hello".getBytes();
for(ChannelHandler ch : clients) {
    ChannelBuffer cb = ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(data);
    ch.write(cb)
}
```